# importing opencv version 3.4.2.17 in python 3.7

Tags: python, opencv, jupyter-notebook

I have already installed opencv in anaconda  prompt by entering the command:

```
pip install opencv-python
```

it installed properly, but I'm unable to import the module in jupyter notebook.I entered the following command in jupyter:

```
import opencv
```

but it's showing ModuleNotFoundError

Also, to resolve anaconda environment issues, I entered the following command in anaconda prompt:

```
conda install -c conda-forge opencv
```

this further downloaded and extracted packages:
libopencv-3.4.1,opencv-3.4.1,py-opencv3.4.1
but still I'm unable to import opencv or libopencv module in my Jupyter notebook.

What should I do to use opencv3.4.2.17 in my python version3.7?

Comment: Isn't it `import cv2`?  Not every package is imported under the same name as the project.  Please try that and report back.

Comment: import cv2 is also showing ModuleNotFoundError in jupyter

Comment: FWIW I just created a 3.7 conda environment and installed opencv using exactly your command, and afterwards `import cv2` worked just fine.  I'd double-check that your jupyter notebook is attached to the environment you think it is.

Comment: How can I check the connection of jupyter notebook with environment?

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for importing opencv is as follows:

`import cv2`

If opencv was correctly installed, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

For installation of OpenCV, use:

```
pip install opencv
```

To import OpenCV, use:

```
import cv2
```